# Estimating a sample size such that its sum has some probability of not crossing some upper bound

Tags: estimation, poisson-distribution

We have a random variable $X\sim Pois(\lambda)$ with $\lambda$ unknown, and given any random sample $S=\{s_1, \ldots, s_{|S|}\}$ generated from $X$, we define $$\text{numsum}(S)=\sum_{i=1}^{|S|}s_i$$.

Our problem is then,

> Given a natural number $L$ and a real number $p\in[0, 100]$, we have to find the biggest natural number $M$ such that if I generate random numbers from $X$ and accumulate them in a set $S_1$ until the set has a size $M$, and then I construct a new set $S_2$ and start accumulating numbers again until $S_2$ has a size $M$, and I repeat this process indefinitely, generating an infinite amount of sets of size $M$, $\text{numsum}(S_i)\leq L$ holds for $p\%$ of the sets (or better).

To estimate $M$, assume we have an initial random sample $Y=\{y_1, \ldots, y_{|Y|}\}$ available where $|Y|$ is under your control (you can get an initial random sample has large as you need, although the shorter the better).

Comment: Isn't this just a restatement of your previous question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/563926/sum-of-sequential-values-from-a-poisson-distribution??

Comment: @whuber Yes but I thought I had deleted the old one already (and I just did) and that is why I asked again with a much less ambiguous specification of the problem in my opnion.

Comment: @whuber besides in my previous question I said "lowest M" which is exactly the opposite that I really want to ask (biggest M), because if I ask for the lowest M, with M = 0 the bound holds 100% of the time.

Comment: If $p$ can be as large as $100$, then $100p\%$ can be as large as $10000\%$

Comment: @Glen_b, that is what happens when one rewrite the questions dozens of tomes. Fixed.

Comment: The problem is that you also deleted the comments.  My comment pointed out that your "numsum" has a Poisson distribution, thereby greatly simplifying the question.

Comment: @whuber I don't think I can really make $X=numsum(S)$ and translate the question in terms of $X$ because I would be destroying information; what we want to estimate is the sample size after all.

Comment: No information is destroyed and much is gained by knowing exactly the distribution of "numsum" for any $|S|.$

Comment: @whuber I will try to rewrite the question to be a bit more clear but I'm afraid of normalize the question the wrong way, although after two days of no answers the question is probably dead already. Anyway, follow-up question (not sure if I did the right thing here opening a new question, but I tried to focus the question on what I tried to do not on what I'm trying to solve): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/564379/contradictory-behaviour-on-sums-of-poisson-variables