# Contradictory behaviour on sums of poisson variables

Tags: normal-distribution, poisson-distribution, normalization

Trying to solve this problem of mine (you don't actually need to read the linked problem, the problem is rephrased below with a different assumption):

[Estimating a sample size such that its sum has some probability of not crossing some upper bound](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/564243/estimating-a-sample-size-such-that-its-sum-has-some-probability-of-not-crossing?noredirect=1#comment1039143_564243)

I started with the assumption that the mean $\lambda$ is known, to see how far I can get, but I got a result whose semantics are confusing me. Such confusing semantics is the reason of doing a separate question.

Rephrasing the problem under such assumption of known $\lambda$:

> Given a natural number $L$ and a real number $p\in[0, 1]$, find the biggest natural number $n$ such as, given $n$ random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, where each $X_i\sim \mathcal{P}(\lambda)$ and with $\lambda\gt 0$, $$\mathbb{P}\biggl[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\leq L\biggr] = p$$

Knowing that the sum of poisson variables is a poisson variable whose mean is the sum of means, and a poisson variable can be approximated by a normal distribution when its mean is big (which in my case is):

$$\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\sim \mathcal{P}(n\lambda)\approx \mathcal{N}(n\lambda, n\lambda)$$

Normalizing:

$$
\mathbb{P}\biggl[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i-n\lambda}{\sqrt{n\lambda}}\leq \frac{L-n\lambda}{\sqrt{n\lambda}}\biggr] = \mathbb{P}\biggl[Z\leq \frac{L-n\lambda}{\sqrt{n\lambda}}\biggr]=p
$$

Now I find the constant $c$ such that $\mathbb{P}[Z\leq c]=p$, name $\alpha^2=n\lambda$, and solve:

$$\frac{L-n\lambda}{\sqrt{n\lambda}} = c\quad\Rightarrow\quad\frac{L-\alpha^2}{\alpha} = c$$
$$\Rightarrow\quad\alpha^2+c\alpha -L=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad\alpha=\frac{-c+\sqrt{c^2+4L}}{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow\quad \boxed{n = \frac{\alpha^2}{\lambda} = \frac{(-c+\sqrt{c^2+4L})^2}{4\lambda}}$$

But according to the formula, if I want a higher probability, e.g., a larger $c$, it calculates a larger $n$. In other words, asking for more probability implies asking for more data to sum, and that confuses me.

I mean, informally speaking, If I sum $n=0$ numbers the result will be below any $L$ for sure. Adding more numbers should increase the probability of being **above** $L$, not the other way around, but the equation above says otherwise. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I made the question a bit shorter now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, all I did looks fine. My misunderstanding was based on my thought that the function

$$
n=f(c)=\frac{(-c+\sqrt{c^2+4L})^2}{4\lambda}
$$

was increasing on $c$. But it's not, it's actually a decreasing function, which means that the highest the requested probability, the lowest the number of terms I have to add; exactly what I thought.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a normal approximation for this. You just look at the [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) $F$ and the [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Inverse_distribution_function_(quantile_function)) $F^{-1}$ of a $\text{Poisson}(n \times \lambda)$ [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution).

You basically want to solve $F(L; n \lambda) \leq p$ or equivalently $F^{-1}(p; n \lambda) \leq L$ in terms of $n \in \text{Integers}$ (or solve the equality in terms of $n \in \text{Reals}$ and then take the floor).

Comment: Ok I will try to look at those functions to know how I should use them. But even if I don't need a normal approximation, is it wrong to use it? In case it is not wrong, what did I do wrong then? Because my final result makes no sense to me.